# How can I give values to webBrowser control text boxes?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

Please go to this website : http://www.dofellow.com/ and see the software video.

This guy is giving values to webBrowser control text boxes from database / datagrid / textbox etc.

Can anyone tell me how is he doing that ? I think every website have different ids for text boxes then how he is giving values to those fields ?

Also, how is he searching for do follow links on google ? Can anyone share the search query with me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this guy gets these text boxes imprecisely. Maybe it won't work correctly for a site with following code:

```
<input type="text" id="email" />   **His code will put the name into this field**
<input type="text" id="displayName" />   **emails will be put here**
<textarea id="comment"></textarea>
```

To change the values of these HTML controls, we can use:

```
WebBrowser wb = new WebBroswer();
wb.Navigate("http://www.google.com");
wb.Document.GetElementById("theID") or GetElementByTagName etc.
```

Comment: How can I submit values to those text boxes ?

Comment: May I know why do you want to do this? Maybe it's just me but the website you linked to smells fishy from miles, as well as your attempt to find "do follow links on Google" and to submit forms. There's a good reason why can't you search for "do follow links" on Google. I'd love to be corrected on this but from your words it sounds that you want to spam the web.